# Access to Lambda is Denied (Non-AWS)

Tags: python, lambda, python-3.4

I'm working in a third party analytic developer with a Python block. When I try using Lambda, I get "Access to Lambda is denied"

Here is the Lambda code I typically use and works in PyDev:

```
res = numpy.split(idxsort, idx_start[1:])
result = list(filter(lambda x: x.size > 1, res))
```

result returns a list of arrays of indexes. Each array represents a unique timestamp and all the locations where that timestamp exists in a matrix

Questions:

Any thoughts on why Lambda Access is denied?

I'm having trouble developing code with same results not using Lambda. Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wait, what?  Are you saying that your third-party developer can't use the lambda, or does Python *actually* say something like that?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Its a third party analytic software that uses block diagram style blueprints and there is a python block option. I developed the python code in PyDev, but it breaks in the software with error "Access to Lambda is Denied".